# Calculating the principal

Tags: finance

By which formula shall I calculate the amount for the following problem:

Let say I want to buy a product, for which, I need to pay monthly installment of Rs500 , for 3 Months and rate of interest is 12% per annum.

The amount which needs to be deposited in saving bank account is ?.

Here its **1470**.

Similarly for 6000 to be received in  3 months the rate of interest is 5.9
Amount deposited = **17824**.

500 - Per month

2 - time in month

0 - Rate of interest p.a --> Principal =**1000**

Not able to understand the formula to calculate the amount deposited

Comment: @Chinny84 I am from programming background this [question](http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/1350/codevita-question?show=8509) was asked here.And I am not able to understand the formula through which the output has been calculated hence asked here.However the answer is mention with the formula used in the post only , but I am not able to understand how it has been concluded to that point.

Comment: @Chinny84 yes..The mathematical calculation is already done (implemented in code) , its just I don't understand how they have formulated it.http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/1350/codevita-question?show=8509 (This is the same question I asked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is

> $PV=a\cdot \left( \Large{
>  \frac{(1+\frac{i}{12})^m-1}{\frac{i}{12}}}\right)                     
>  \cdot \Large{\frac{1}{(1+\frac{i}{12})^m}}$

**PV**:= Present Value

**a:**= Annuity

**i:**= Annual percentage rate

**m:**= Number of months

---

In your second example the calculation is

$PV=6000\cdot \left( \Large{ \frac{(1+\frac{0.059}{12})^3-1}{\frac{0.059}{12}}}\right)                                                               \cdot \Large{\frac{1}{(1+\frac{0.059}{12})^3}}\normalsize{\approx 17,824.44}$